# worst case to average case reduction in non-cyclotomic Ring LWE

Tags: ring-lwe, ntru, reduction

I understand that we need 2-to-power cyclotomic ring to show that the solving decision RLWE is as hard as solving search RLWE.

Is there any chance to prove it without 'cyclotomic' property?

For example, in NTRU prime, using Z[x]/(x^p-x-1), can we show worst case reduction from LWE?